# How to append unique counts to end of strings in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm looking for something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685851/how-to-append-unique-numbers-to-a-list-of-strings), but in Python.

I have a list with repeated elements:

```
["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange"]
```

I'm looking for a list expression or a methodology that will give me:

```
["Apple 1", "Orange 1", "Apple 2", "Pear 1", "Banana 1", "Apple 3", "Apple 4", "Orange 2"]
```

Obviously, preserving order is very important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`collections.Counter`*

```
from collections import Counter

mapping = {k : iter(range(1, v + 1)) for k, v in Counter(lst).items()} 
lst2 = ['{} {}'.format(x, next(mapping[x])) for x in lst]

print(lst2)
['Apple 1', 'Orange 1', 'Apple 2', 'Pear 1', 'Banana 1', 'Apple 3', 'Apple 4', 'Orange 2']
```

---

**Option 2**
*`itertools.count`*

[juan suggests the use of `itertools.count`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308866/how-to-append-unique-counts-to-end-of-strings-in-a-list/46308940?noredirect=1#comment79579900_46308940), a great alternative to the above.

```
from itertools import count

mapping = {k : count(1) for k in set(lst)}   
lst2 = ['{} {}'.format(x, next(mapping[x])) for x in lst]

print(lst2)
['Apple 1', 'Orange 1', 'Apple 2', 'Pear 1', 'Banana 1', 'Apple 3', 'Apple 4', 'Orange 2']
```

The difference between this and the one above is in the manner in which `mapping` is defined.

Comment: you could use an `itertools.count` object instead, and avoid the use of `Counter`, so `mapping` would just be `{k:count() for e in x}`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Works fantastic! If you want to add it to your answer, let me know and I'll remove it from mine.

Comment: I am wondering which one would be faster, have you done some benchmarking?

Comment: @norok2 No, I haven't had the chance to do it, but I expect them to be about the same...

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way seems obvious enough:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter()
>>> x = ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange"]
>>> new_x = []
>>> for item in x:
...     counts[item] += 1
...     new_x.append(f"{item}{counts[item]}")
...
>>> new_x
['Apple1', 'Orange1', 'Apple2', 'Pear1', 'Banana1', 'Apple3', 'Apple4', 'Orange2']
>>>
```

Comment: Note to readers: `f` strings work on python3.6 (?) and above. For older versions, use `str.format`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange"]
a = Counter(data)

for i in range(len(data) - 1, -1, -1):
    index = str(a[data[i]])
    a[data[i]] -= 1
    data[i] += ' ' + index
```

Now `data` is equal to `['Apple 1', 'Orange 1', 'Apple 2', 'Pear 1', 'Banana 1', 'Apple 3', 'Apple 4', 'Orange 2']`.

This modifies the given list in-place.