# ListBox (multiselect) selected indexes

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, listbox

I have a `ListBox` which supports `Multi-Select` and I need a way to retrieve all the selected indexes as a `List<int>`.

for example:

```
Listbox
{
    item 1 - not selected
    item 2 - selected
    item 3 - selected
    item 4 - not selected
}
```

So the selected indexes `List<int>` will look like:

```
List<int>() { 1, 2 };
```

Comment: something like "string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);" maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
   list.Add(listBox1.Items.IndexOf(item));// Add selected indexes to the List<int>
}
```

Or with linq:

```
List<int> list = (from object obj in listBox1.SelectedItems 
                  select listBox1.Items.IndexOf(obj)).ToList();
```

Comment: What if two of the selected items are equal? Won't `IndexOf()` then return the first one's index twice?

Comment: If the the selection contains duplicate elements, you'll need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509810/1168116) instead.